# How to add two div positions in same xpath to ignore duplicate values?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

On order confirmation page We have 2 products and I want to get the Item Names but the Item name + item Addon Tags are same so now the list is 4,
I want only the Item name,
Here is My HTML code

```
        <div class="grid_3 d-grid_10">
            <p class="m-confirmation-modal-print-item-title">
                Beautiful in Blue
                        (Standard)
                        </p>
        </div>
        <div class="grid_3 d-grid_10">
                    <p class="m-confirmation-modal-print-item-title">
                        2 Balloons&nbsp;
                        mylar balloons:</p>
    </div>

        <div class="grid_3 d-grid_10">
            <p class="m-confirmation-modal-print-item-title">
                Golden Glow
                        (Standard)
                        </p>
        </div>
        <div class="grid_3 d-grid_10">
                    <p class="m-confirmation-modal-print-item-title">
                        2 Balloons&nbsp;
                        mylar balloons:</p>
                </div>
```

Comment: Code trials? Any error? Which language binding of Selenium?

Comment: What you try and what is your problem?

Comment: List<WebElement> billingPageItemNames = getDriver().findElements(By.xpath("//p[@class='m-confirmation-modal-print-item-title']"));
   //1st 
   WebElement p1 = billingPageItemNames.get(0);
   //3rd
   WebElement p2 = billingPageItemNames.get(2);
   List<WebElement> newbillingPageItemslist= new ArrayList ();
   newbillingPageItemslist.add(p1);
   newbillingPageItemslist.add(p2);

Comment: I want to get the Items list so instaed of writing the get list can we write an xpath which contains the item name postion

Comment: @user3538483 , what do you mean by *contains the item name postion*? What is your desired output?

Comment: Please post a link to the page or more of the relevant HTML.

Comment: @JeffC It is a typical harassment to ask each and every OP to provide link to the original webpage for your specific help. Please take care. Moreover please don't change the _HTML_ at your disposal. Else all the existing answer may become invalid. For the time being I am reverting back the question to it's initial state.

Comment: @DebanjanB I don't ask "each and every" OP to provide a link.. it's actually pretty rare for me to ask that and I only ask it when necessary. It's hard to tell if this is complete HTML for this area or if it's just specific repeated elements. I don't change the HTML on a whim. I formatted it with proper indents so that it reasonably read because the indent was not correct before. I've reverted it back to the correct indents (I ran it through an HTML beautifier). Your locators shouldn't be so fragile to break when proper indents are included.

Comment: @JeffC: While that is good advice in general, it's still not a good idea to change the indentation of someone else's code when there is a considerable risk of breaking their locators or other tests. You don't know how much control someone has over the markup they are testing.

Comment: @JeffC Putting aside the number of instances you have asked for a link for the time being, if you were able to interpret/understand the HTML properly to edit it for betterment, you wouldn't have **raised a counter question** in the first place. Perhaps it won't be wise to change the HTML when other contributors can interpret the HTML quite well and construct canonical answers.

Comment: @BoltClock Can you give an example of when changing only indents would break a locator? I'm not talking whitespace editing, I'm talking indents. With your comment, I'm taking it that you are stating that HTML cannot be beautified... ever. You don't really mean that, do you?

Comment: @DebanjanB I put the HTML through a beautifier to fix the indent because it was hard to read. I do that on many questions when it's clear that the HTML is not properly (or near properly) indented. That is completely irrelevant to asking the OP to provide more HTML or a link to the page to better understand the scenario. You asked three questions and posted an answer before getting any responses from OP... if you were able to interpret/understand the question you wouldn't have needed to "raise a counter question" in the first place... you see how that logic makes no sense?

Comment: @JeffC No, you have no idea how much destruction you had done by formatting the  HTML with beautifier. Feel free to realize the difference between the two HTML [OP initial HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/54177915/1) and [your beautified HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/54177915/4). I am sure OP wouldn't receive any working answer with the _beautified HTML_. Perhaps you need to understand how `text()`, `contains()` and `normalize-space()` works differently in conjunction to **XPath**

Comment: @JeffC Perhaps those **three questions** are mandatory info for any _Selenium_ related question which are required by the StackOverflow contributors to construct canonical answers. As OP didn't provide those as a contributor it's my responsibility to ask him those information through a counter question at the same time a best fit answer, which I did. So what is your question now?

Comment: @DebanjanB I think your three questions are fine. My point is that if those three questions are "mandatory info" and "required ... to construct canonical answers" as you state, why did you post your answer before you got a response? A simple point is that OP didn't post any code, didn't tag the question Java, didn't put in the question description that he wanted Java but you posted an answer in Java. How do you know that's a "canonical answer" if you don't even know what language he's using?

Comment: @JeffC What's wrong in lending out a helping hand as a _Tag Contributor_. StackOverflow have dedicated team for `Help and Improvement`, `Low Quality Post`, `First Post`. You really don't have to bother for the quality so hard. If something isn't clear, take your action and move on. Please don't stretch these trival issues so far.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java you can simply use a [Set](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_set_interface.htm) which won't contain any duplicate elements as follows:

```
List<WebElement> productElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//p[@class='m-confirmation-modal-print-item-title']"));
HashSet<String> productNames = new HashSet<>();
for (WebElement productElement : productElements)
{
    String productName = productElement.getAttribute("innerHTML");
    productNames.add(productName);
}
for(int i = 0; i < productNames.size(); i++) 
{
    System.out.println(productNames.get(i));
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem... now you will have 3 items (at least) instead of the desired 2.

Comment: @JeffC You completely misread the _HTML_ OP have provided. OP clearly mentioned in the question heading s/he wants to ignore duplicates. If you can spend some time to interpret the HTML there are **3** different products as in `Beautiful in Blue(Standard)`, `Golden Glow(Standard)` and `2 Balloons&nbsp; mylar balloons:` (duplicated). Is there something else I am missing?

Comment: You might be right... I took the "2 Balloons&nbsp; mylar balloons:" as a (repeated) description of the main products, "Beautiful in Blue (Standard)" and "Golden Glow (Standard)." That's why I asked for a link to the page... to see what the more full HTML of the page is and answer that question.

Comment: I edited your code to add whitespace so that I could remove the downvote. We'll see when OP comes back what the actual products are.