# How to paste the text copied in clipboard through Selenium and Java on MacOS

Tags: macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, sendkeys

I want to paste some text in one of the textbox in MACOS. I am trying below code. But Control + v and Command + v both are not working. I have also seen that this is known issue, but not sure if it is resolved or not.
https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/5919
The code is as below.

```
public void copyToClipbord(String copyTo)
{
    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    StringSelection str = new StringSelection(copyTo);
   clipboard.setContents(str, null );
}


// And paste into required input/testfield/testarea field object
public void pasteText(WebElement element, String value)
{
    copyToClipbord(value);
    element.click();
    //new Actions( driver ).contextClick( element ).sendKeys( "P" ).sendKeys("\n").perform();
    element.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL, "V");
}
```

I have also tried context click, that also does not work. I have validated that copyToClipboard function is working properly. Please suggest me, if there are any work around to this.

Thanks,
Umang

Answer (score 1):

You have to select  paste option in pop up which open after right and then click on paste option.
[image]

You can write code like this.

```
        new Actions(driver ).contextClick(element).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
   .sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
    .sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).
    sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).perform();
```

For me Paste option is present at 5th position. So I have written sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN) 5 times. You can write this as per your requirement.

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: Hi Ajay,
Thanks for your reply. But after contextClick the ARROW_DOWN does not work. Have you tried it by any chance in macos? I see this issue only with macos in chrome browser.
Thanks,
Umang

Comment: Hi Umang, I have tried the same for opening link in new tab and new window. It is working fine for me on macOs. I have tried this on firefox browser.

Comment: Hi Ajay,
As i had mentioned i am facing this issue in MACOS in chrome browser and our application supports only chrome. Let me know if it works for you in chrome as well. If so then please let me know your MACOS version.
Thanks,
Umang

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned *`copyToClipboard()` function is working properly* moving forward to send the *character sequence* through `sendKeys()` you can use the following solution:

```
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.io.IOException;

copyToClipbord(value);
String data = (String) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor); 
element.sendKeys(data);
```

Comment: That doesn't paste the string into the field... that's the same as typing. If he wanted to do that, he wouldn't have put the string (that he already has, given the code in the question) into the clipboard only to turn around and type it into the field.

Comment: @JeffC Seems another misinterpretation from you just like [previous instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54177915/how-to-add-two-div-positions-in-same-xpath-to-ignore-duplicate-values/54178148#comment95205132_54178148). OP have clearly mentioned `want to paste some text`, `Control + v` and `Command + v` are not working. Also _..copyToClipboard function is working properly.._ so of-coarse the text is copied to the clipboard. OP needs help to copy the content from _clipboard_ to the element. Can you help us with your tests how you concluded `That doesn't paste the string into the field`

Comment: Because `.sendKeys()` isn't the same as CTRL+V.

Comment: To elaborate further... OP included the code for `copyToClipbord()` so clearly he is *putting the string into the clipboard* as part of the test. If all he wanted to do is sendkeys (like you did), there would be no need to use `copyToClipbord()`... he could have just used `.sendKeys(copyTo)` and not written `pasteText()` that attempts to do CTRL+V (paste from clipboard).

Answer (score 0):

public String copyFromClipboard() {
boolean found = false

```
String data = ''

int count = 0

while (found == false) {
    count++

    try {
        WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()

        Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard()

        data = ((Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)) as String)

        if (!(data.contains('https'))) {
            found = false
        } else {
            println((('Found the data in the ' + count) + ' try: ') + data)

            return data
            
            found = true

            break
        }
    }
    catch (UnsupportedFlavorException e) {
        println(e)
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        println(e)
    } 
}
```

}